# kotlin canvas.drawRect draws outside of the canvas

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, canvas, graphics

So I'm trying to draw a rectangle in kotlin and I have a class that does this but I need the size of the canvas to do this so in my main view I call the classes setCanvas() function in my onDraw() function, something like this.

main view

```
var rectangle = Rectangle()
override fun onDraw(canvas:Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    rectangle.setNewCanvas(canvas)

    rectangle.show()
    rectangle.update()

    invalidate()
}
```

class

```
class Rectangle {
    private var canvas: Canvas? = null
    var x = 0
    var speed = 10
    fun setNewCanvas(newCanvas: Canvas)
        if(canvas == null) {
            canvas = newCanvas
            x = canvas?.width!!
        }
    }

    fun show() {
        canvas?.drawRect(x.toFloat(), 0F, x.toFloat() - 100, 1000F, Paint(Color.RED))
    }

    fun update() {
        x -= speed
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the rectangle to move across the screen but when I check if canvas is null in setNewCanvas() it moves but the rectangle is drawn above the canvas in the banner where the apps project name is. If I don't check if canvas is null then the value of x gets reassigned to the width with every call so the rectangle never moves.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not encapsulate the function of modifying coordinates into Rectangle, and you cannot set canvas repeatedly.

```kotlin
var x = 0
var speed = 10

fun update() {
  x -= speed
}

override fun onDraw(canvas:Canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(x.toFloat(), 0F, x.toFloat() - 100, 1000F, Paint(Color.RED))
    rectangle.update()
    invalidate()
}
```

Comment: But I'm not setting it repeatedly, I check if canvas is null every time I call setNewCanvas(). And why is encapsulating the coordinate modifiers bad? should I have something like this in Rectangle instead? fun update(speed) { x -= speed }

Comment: I know that every call to `show()` in your code will detect whether `canvas` is `null`, but I think this has no effect. Because if you need to pass the `canvas` object to the `show()` function you define, you can also pass parameters in this way of `show(canvas)`.

In `onDraw()`, the canvas object must not be `null`. The function of drawing can be done in `onDraw()` function, including updating coordinates and `invalidate` can be done in `onDraw()`.